# Scrolling with touchpad in vscode is jerky

Tags: 20.04, scrolling, visual-studio-code

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my old Mac book pro from 2015. I am experiencing issues with scrolling with the touchpad with 3rd party applications. Now matter how fast or "long" I swipe with two fingers the screen is always scrolled up or down just a one nudge.

I was able to solve the issue with Firefox with the instructions mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1149543/1574506, namely putting `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` to /etc/environment file.

However, I am experiencing the same issue with visual studio code. I have tried to set `Editor: Smooth Scrolling` setting on in vscode but it does not have any effect.

How to fix the issue? Can the issue be my Mac or is the issue independent of hardware? Are other Ubuntu users facing similar issues with vscode?

Comment: Based on https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/h95fgi/kinetic_scrolling/ and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41878 it seems that at the moment there is no way of having kinetic scrolling in Ubuntu in vscode. I feel not having kinetic scrolling built-in is a major usability issue with Ubuntu.